# How to use multiple .sitemap files in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I think I'm missing something obvious about sitemaps.

I'm trying to use a repeater to generate some navigation for a new sitemap we have on our site.  But I don't want to use our normal Web.sitemap file, I want to use our new one...we'll call it "Web.NEW.sitemap".

The code seems somewhat obvious to a point...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptMyRepeater" DataSourceID="mySitemap" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        blah blah blah
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="mySitemap" runat="server" />
```

But how do I get SiteMapDataSource to use Web.NEW.sitemap instead of the default sitemap?  I thought adding an attribute like:

```
SiteMapProvider="Web.NEW.sitemap"
```

ought to do it, but no dice.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to configure your web.config properly to make use of the [SiteMapDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sitemapdatasource.sitemapprovider.aspx) property. Use the [SiteMap element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1e333zt4.aspx):

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="oldProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="oldProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="web.sitemap" />
    <add name="newProvider" type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider" siteMapFile="Web.NEW.sitemap" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

and then set the SiteMapProvider property to the provider's name from the web.config file.

```
SiteMapProvider="newProvider"
```

Comment: @NKhan, I set the SiteMapProvider in my CodeBehind file, so after setting the SiteMapProvider, I had to `DataBind()` my SiteMap and then my Menu (which I was using the SiteMap for):  

`_siteMap.SiteMapProvider = "newProvider";`  
`_siteMap.DataBind();`  
`_menu.DataBind();`  

Do you need to do this? Does this work for you?

Comment: I don't know how to get the formatting to work properly, but those are three separate commands that I wanted on three separate lines.