# asp.net sitemap changing runtime

Tags: asp.net, sitemap

I have an asp.net website with different user types like admin, registered user. Each user type has different menu options.

I have created a common master page for all types of users, but designed different sitemap files for different user types.

What I am trying to do is, after login according to the user type the sitemap should change in Master Page.

Here is the code I tried in master page loading. It is showing me error like

```
**The SiteMapProvider 'Principal.sitemap' cannot be found.**
```

I tried with and without .sitemap extension. (I have principal.sitemap and other sitemaps)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["usertype"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("loginpage.aspx");
            return;
        }

        String usertype = Session["usertype"].ToString();

        if (usertype == "Principal")
        {
            SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "Principal.sitemap";
        }
        else if (usertype == "Administrator")
        {

            //SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "Administrator";
        }
        else if (usertype == "Student")
        {
            SiteMapDataSource1.SiteMapProvider = "Student";

        }
        foo.DataBind(); 
}

Here is my Master Page aspx code part.

 <asp:SiteMapDataSource  ID="SiteMapDataSource1" ShowStartingNode="false" runat="server" />
                <ul id="cssmenu1">
                    <li><a id="A1" href="index.aspx" runat="server">Home</a></li>

                    <asp:Repeater ID="foo" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1" EnableViewState="false" 
                                    runat="server" onitemcommand="foo_ItemCommand">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <li>
                                <a href='<%#Eval("url") %>'><%#Eval("Title") %></a>

                                <ul>
                                    <asp:Repeater ID="bar" DataSource='<%# ((SiteMapNode) Container.DataItem).ChildNodes %>' runat="server">
                                        <ItemTemplate>
                                            <li><a href='<%#Eval("url") %>'><%#Eval("Title") %></a></li>
                                        </ItemTemplate>
                                    </asp:Repeater>
                                </ul>

                            </li>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: are you sure path of the sitemap is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you registered them in your web.config as this question demonstrates?

[How to use multiple .sitemap files in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916681/how-to-use-multiple-sitemap-files-in-asp-net)

Is so, you may need to check that the name is qualified properly.